# Error:(72) unknown element <receiver> found

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-studio-3.0, dji-sdk

I am using Dji-SDK. Recently i migrated the SDK from version 4.2 to 4.3.2. After changing the dji-sdk.aar in the libs folder i am not able  to build because of the merge issues in the manifest. The merged manifest in build is getting created as follows.

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <receiver
        android:name="dji.logic.receiver.DJIPilotStartupReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="dji.permission.sdk.wifi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="dji.pilot.STARTUP" />
            <action android:name="dji.go3.STARTUP" />
            <action android:name="dji.go4.STARTUP" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <application
        android:name="com.sample.app.LinkApplication"
...
```

I know that the `receiver` tag should come under `application` tag. But in the merged manifest the tag is under the `uses-permission` tag and showing an error. Is it an Sdk error or is it wrong on my side ?
Error is

```
Error:(71) unknown element <receiver> found
```

Here is the build.gradle.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 7
        versionName "4.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
        retrolambda {
            javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            incremental true
        }
        buildConfigField "boolean", "DRONE_DEBUG", property('DRONE_DEBUG')
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", property('BASE_URL')
        buildConfigField "String", "LINK_DRONE_URL", property('LINK_DRONE_URL')
        buildConfigField "String", "LINK_SENSOR_URL", property('LINK_SENSOR_URL')
        resValue "string", "api_key_dji_sdk", "################"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Link"
        dimension "default"
        applicationId = "com.sample.app"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0')
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation('org.jscience:jscience:4.3.1', {
        exclude group: 'org.javolution', module: 'javolution'
    })
    //implementation 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.3.2' (i have tried this too after removeing the dji-sdk.aar)
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

I am using

- Android Studio 3.0 Beta 4
- Dji-sdk 4.3.2

Comment: did you try merging the manifests

Comment: I am trying to build. and the Error occurs.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try disabling the `AAPT2` by adding `android.enableAapt2=false` to your `gradle.properties` file.

> Builds may fail while AAPT2 is enabled. Additionally, AAPT2 is
>   currently not compatible with Robelectric. If your build fails due to
>   an AAPT2 resource processing issue or you want to use Roboelectric,
>   you can disable AAPT2 by setting `android.enableAapt2=false` in your
>   `gradle.properties` file and restarting the Gradle daemon by running
>   `./gradlew --stop` from the command line.

Reference : [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html)

I was using Android studio 3.0 beta 5 In which I disabled the `AAPT2` and it resolved my error.

**UPDATE :**

As [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3779042/jay) has mentioned another solution could be update Android Studio to `3.1.1`. Since updating has solved issue for him. I haven't cross checked though.

**UPDATE : 01 March 2020**
As [Tarit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5886712/tarit-ray) has mentioned, `android.enableAapt2=false` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: adding `android.enableAapt2=false` to `gradle.properties` file worked.

Comment: Confirmed fix on Android Studio 3.0

Comment: I am not sure about fix since my project is still not working without adding `android.enableAapt2=false` in `Studio 3.0`

Comment: I can confirm it also works for me now with DJI SDK 4.4.1 and Android Studio 3.1...

Comment: If it was corrected in a previous version then there is a regression. I get the problem on Android Studio 3.1.2

Comment: Sadly this is not really a solution. In my case using android.enableAapt2=false makes me hit a different bug in AaPt that don't allow running the aplication...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513051/failed-to-execute-aapt-nosuchelementexception-at-abstractindexedlistiterator-ne

Comment: Well, sorry this solution couldn't help you.

Comment: @rsan try deleting the .gradle in root folder and try to rebuild after removing the android.enableAapt option.

Comment: WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.