# Failed to execute aapt (NoSuchElementException at AbstractIndexedListIterator.next(AbstractIndexedListIterator.java:80)

Tags: android, gradle, build

The project gets built without error from Android Studio -> Build -> Build APKs and after installation it works fine. But running the project with a Run Configuration gives the following error:

```
    Failed to execute aapt

    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':MyProject:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForFlavorDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunDependenciesApkBuilder.transform(InstantRunDependenciesApkBuilder.java:152)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:809)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:797)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.generateSplitApkResourcesAp(InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.java:373)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.generateSplitApkResourcesAp(InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.java:321)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.generateSplitApk(InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.java:210)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunDependenciesApkBuilder.transform(InstantRunDependenciesApkBuilder.java:149)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIndexedListIterator.next(AbstractIndexedListIterator.java:80)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:315)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:263)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.makePackageProcessBuilder(AaptV1.java:202)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.makeValidatedPackage(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:67)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:807)
        ... 57 more
```

The error appeared after moving to `Android Studio 3.1`, `Gradle 4.4` and adding `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` to the build.gradle file. The Run Configuration worked fine just before update. The project is JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 compatible. I also removed `android.enableAapt2 = false` from gradle.properties since it's deprecated. Any ideas what could cause that?

**UPDATE:**
`gradle.properties` was cached in `C:\Users\MyUser\.gradle\gradle.properties` for Windows. Obviously that file was used even when I switched to the wrapper. The changes to the project's `gradle.properties` didn't took any effect until I removed the cache. When `android.enableAapt2 = false` was actually removed, the warning was gone and I could enable Instant Run.

Comment: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. See this gradle o/p and dig into it.

Comment: I have the same setup as you. I only get your error with `android.enableAapt2 = false` (which you said you removed). For me removing it gives me other errors.. :-/

Comment: @RoySolberg, it could be some weird gradle cache happening, because I've removed it, but the build still gives the warning for using it (being deprecated).

Comment: @Galya did you check both the gradle.properties file and the extra arguments you pass to gradle from Android Studio?

Comment: @RoySolberg open a new question for these errors or file a new bug on here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533 - AAPT1 will be deprecated soon, so it would be good to figure out what's happening in your project with AAPT2 before that happens.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska, gradle.properties was cached in C:\Users\MyUser\.gradle\gradle.properties for Windows. Obviously that file was used even when I switched to the wrapper. The changes to the project's gradle.properties didn't took any effect until I removed the cache.

Comment: @Galya great, thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is a bug in gradle plugin code that calls AAPT1. It was fixed but not cherry-picked, it should be available in the next released version (it should be fixed in 3.2 canary 3 and newer).
This only affects AAPT1. Removing the android.enableAapt2=false flag will make the code not hit this codepath (check your gradle.properties file and the extra arguments you pass to gradle from Android Studio).

Comment: Morning Izabela, the OP has already mentioned that "I also removed android.enableAapt2 = false from gradle.properties since it's deprecated"

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal I know :) but this flag *must* be set somewhere for AAPT1 to be used. Most likely it was set in two places, so removing it from just one doesn't change it.

Comment: With the above change, the OP will also have to upgrade the buildToolsVersion to avoid other kinds of errors.

Comment: With gradle plugin 3.1 you can now just not specify the buildToolsVersion at all and it will pick up the appropriate version automatically. :)

Answer (score 11):

I did below and it solved this issue:

1. In gradle.properties file:

   android.enableAapt2=false
2. I disabled the Instant Run.**(Important)**

Comment: This work for me as well but In the end of 2018 enableAapt2 will not be used anymore

Answer (score 3):

In your gradle properties:
**remove android.enableAapt2=false**, and **upgrade the buildToolVersion** in your app build.gradle and in all the other modules(if used) too.

Run the command **gradlew --info assembleDebug** in your terminal and check for other errors and if you find them then manually go and fix them.
In my case there was a 9 patch image which was causing all the trouble.

Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Or

Try to disable instant run feature and see if it works.

Or

Try and enable multiDexEnabled.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Or

File -> Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Removing instant run fixed it. It's fine to be disabled on my fast PC, but for the other developers it may not. Can you give me info on why that's the cause.

Comment: i don't think this error will come if your build varient is DEBUG. Are you running the app in release mode?

Comment: It's debug for sure

Comment: It is the instant run code hitting a code-path in the gradle plugin that calls AAPT1. Instead of disabling instant-run, you should enable AAPT2.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow any of the following ways to fix the issue:

`For Android studio 3.1 or <3.2`

1. Update gradle.properties file with `android.enableAapt2=false`
2. Disable Instant Run(Ctrl+shift+A(win+Linux) or Command+shift+A(Mac) then search for Instant run).

`For Android studio 3.2 or later`

1. Update Android studio to 3.2
2. Update gradle.properties file with `android.enableAapt2=true`
3. You can keep remain enable the Instant run now.

Answer (score 1):

Open the **File** tab and then click on **Invalidate Caches \ Restart**.
*It worked for me* :).