# Android studio: I am getting the following error "java.util.NoSuchElementException".However, I can't trace the error

Tags: android-studio, exception, error-handling

I am getting the following error

> java.util.NoSuchElementException

When I click on it to reveal more information, this is what it says.

> Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Unlike previous errors, it doesn't show where the error is coming from. How do I fix this issue? I am looking through all my files and nothing seems to be giving me an error. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solution

Comment: No, I try setting break points, but nothing works.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513051/failed-to-execute-aapt-nosuchelementexception-at-abstractindexedlistiterator-ne/49515823#49515823

Answer (score 34, accepted):

@Izabela is right. However, in my case, I navigated to **File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run** and disabled it by simply unchecking the topmost checkbox (which was enabled by default). Its working perfectly for me (till now). I am running Android Studio 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Have you found the reason? It is working for me also(Android Studio 3.2 beta 4). Thanks.

Comment: @ree1991 I'm not sure about the actual reason, but please see Izabela Orlowska's comment to Akshay Shah's solution below :-)

Answer (score 12):

try adding this to your gradle.properties file

```
android.enableAapt2=true
```

Comment: It is a bug in gradle plugin code that calls AAPT1. It was fixed but not cherry-picked, it should be available in the next released version (it should be fixed in 3.2 canary 3 and newer).
This only affects AAPT1. Removing the android.enableAapt2=false flag (or adding android.enableAapt2=true last) will make the code not hit this codepath.

Comment: this option is not deprecated and does not have any effect

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to fix this issue:

**1st approach for Android studio 3.1 or <3.2**

1. Update gradle.properties file with `android.enableAapt2=false`
2. Disable Instant Run(Ctrl+shift+A(win+Linux) or Command+shift+A(Mac) then search for Instant run).

**2nd approach for Android studio 3.2 or later:**

1. Update Android studio to 3.2
2. Update gradle.properties file with `android.enableAapt2=true`
3. You can keep remain enable the Instant run now.

Comment: `android.enableAapt2` option is not deprecated and does not have any effect