# JUnit5IdeaTestRunner fails running unit tests

Tags: android, junit5

Suddenly Android Studio can't run unit tests for one of my modules.
I get the error:

```
Internal Error occurred. java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:856)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5TestRunnerUtil.createSelector(JUnit5TestRunnerUtil.java:181)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit5TestRunnerUtil.java:70)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

The only thing I need to know is whether this is a known issue.
Please notice that the unit tests of all the modules succeed if I run them in the external terminal or in the terminal in Android Studio or on the CI.
And if I run on Android Studio the same unit test configuration, changing only the module then everything works fine.

Please don't ask me to post the `build.gradle` files. Although it is likely that the problem is there, they are too big and more importantly if that is the problem, I wouldn't expect you to debug it.

Comment: Did you try this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523739/android-studio-i-am-getting-the-following-error-java-util-nosuchelementexcepti

Comment: Thank you. None of the suggested methods worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reported [here](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5/issues/145) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209506). Actually it's an issue in IntelliJ Idea. There are no workaround for now :(

Answer (score 0):

This issue occur when i use Android studio version 3.4.2 and it was fixed by Android Studio version 3.6.1