# NoSuchElementException after Android Studio upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, aapt

I re-installed the latest version of Android Studio, after that I cannot run any application.
There is what I caught:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>       at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>       ... 32 more
>   Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunDependenciesApkBuilder.transform(InstantRunDependenciesApkBuilder.java:152)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>       ... 48 more
>   Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>       at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:809)
>       at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:797)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.generateSplitApkResourcesAp(InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.java:373)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.generateSplitApkResourcesAp(InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.java:321)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.generateSplitApk(InstantRunSplitApkBuilder.java:210)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunDependenciesApkBuilder.transform(InstantRunDependenciesApkBuilder.java:149)
>       ... 51 more
>   Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIndexedListIterator.next(AbstractIndexedListIterator.java:80)
>       at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:315)
>       at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:263)
>       at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.makePackageProcessBuilder(AaptV1.java:202)
>       at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.makeValidatedPackage(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:67)
>       at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
>       at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:807)
>       ... 56 more

**I am using:**

- Android Studio 3.1
- JDK ver. 1.8.0_161
- Gradle ver. 4.4
- Android plugin version 3.1.0
- also android.enableAapt2=false

**What I tried:**

- to run my previous applications
- to create a new project and run it
- Clean/Rebuild

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to execute aapt (NoSuchElementException at AbstractIndexedListIterator.next(AbstractIndexedListIterator.java:80)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513051/failed-to-execute-aapt-nosuchelementexception-at-abstractindexedlistiterator-ne)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, so I just changed the version of **gradle plugin** in **3.0.0** and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run`

and uncheck `Enable Instant Run`.